# Facebook page is not loading properly in mx:html (Adobe AIR) outside IDE

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, air

Adobe AIR application which was working perfectly earlier; is not working now. No idea whether it is due to any recent change in Facebook or Adobe AIR.

I have added the component mx:HTML to display http://facebook.com content. In the development environment (Flash Builder 4.5) after logging in facebook successfully; I can see the TimeLine contents and updates properly. But after build when executed outside the IDE; I am able to login facebook but the timeline or updates are not being displayed properly.

Anybody facing similar issue and has a fix; please provide the solution.

uncaughtScriptException gives following two errors...

TypeError: Result of expression 'bigPipe' [undefined] is not an object.

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: console

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue, if you catch the javascript errors you will notice that facebook is using some library that fails in AIR, then if you google that exact error you will find similar issues. My solution was to use the FB API and reimplement the functionality(in my case share) , other alternatives is to fix that library or FB code to make it work. I don't remember the details but I fixed it  a week ago. 
Check the docs for catching the JS errors [uncaughtScriptException](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/HTML.html#event%3auncaughtScriptException)

I am wondering if that library has code for each browser that it supports and on AIR it fails, maybe changing useragent will help, you need to check the javascript code to see where it fails

Comment: @user3793383 do yo mean it works in debug mode? add that event handler and make sure to write the details in a log file, then edit your question with the result